# Wrong password while extracting zip file

Tags: passwords, zip, 7-zip, winrar, winzip

I had used C# code to create Password protected zip files,

But while extracting all the files inside zip gets except one large *txt* file, and for that particular file all different tools (default windows zip, 7zip, WinZip, WinRar) gives an error as ***Wrong Password***

Now special thing to note is, that text file is very large in size (around few GBs but <10GB), whereas I am able to extract logs with smaller size of that particular file, but I am not getting the exact root cause of this.

Comment: We have no idea what you may have done in your application which may be the cause. As such it's very hard to answer this

Comment: [Zip archives can have multiple passwords for different contained files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489759/108618), so *maybe* you're using a wrong password indeed. Please note we don't know anything about your C# code and its quirks (on the other hand we probably shouldn't, as Super User is not about programming). If I were you I would try to reproduce the issue with files of various sizes in various order to confirm size is a factor. Or maybe your custom code ignores [the limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Limits) somehow?

Comment: Thanks for help and I agree users here shouldn't be concerned about my c# code, but just clarifying ambiguity about 2 possible problems, 1. There is no diff pwd for that particular file as all diff files are zipped together only. 2. File is not that large in a way to cross the limit. And besides this I am using same thing successfully from long ago.

Comment: Is there any possibility that, if files being archived are changed by some other application/process while zip creation is in progress, it might get corrupted? And give us above problem?

Comment: Your comments should be [edit]ed into the question. Also please note at the moment there is no explicit question in the question body, so literally adding `is there any possibility [...] it might get corrupted? And give us above problem?` will fix the whole post on the idea of corruption originating from another process. It may not be the (main) question you wanted to ask. And since this is a broad question about "*any* possibility", the general answer is "yes". It may not be the answer you seek. Therefore while editing please state clearly what your question really is.